# Is there any way to copy request content?

Tags: mitmproxy

The problem is that it's indeed cp1252 (yes, I hate retarded people too) character in the body.

```
curl -kx127.0.0.8:8080 'http://httpbin.org/post' -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=a' --data-binary $'--a\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name="ctl00$BodyContent$txtAtesia"\r\n\r\nDuk\xeb\r\n--a--\r\n'
```

I've tried request.content and request.raw_content both, mitmproxy crashes. SO doesn't want me to post traceback, but it's reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, request.text works.

Should mitmproxy developers happen to pass by, they can deal with the crash though:)

Comment: If you have a reproducible test case, can you please file an issue on GitHub? That would be highly appreciated. Thanks! :)

Comment: @MaximilianHils, alas, cannot, I don't have account on github. I've plenty of bugs for different modules, but since all the bug trackers are now on github, I'm left on my own:)

Comment: @MaximilianHils, to add why I don't have account on github. They refuse to fix their mail sending infrastructure, so I just cannot register, however I liked…